# nvarchar field has wrong encoding when loaded from SQL server

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, encoding, sql-server-2012

I have table with column `MasName` of type `nvarchar(100)`. I am using SQL Server 2012 and Entity Framework 6 to work with database. I have DetailsView where I always bind one relevant record:

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="masDetailView" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False"
SelectMethod="GetMas" UpdateMethod="UpdateMas" ItemType="NSMAS.DAL.Mas"
AutoGenerateEditButton="True">
<Fields>
<asp:TemplateField>
 <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:Label runat="server" ID="nameLbl" Text='<%#: Item.MasName %>'></asp:Label>
 </ItemTemplate>
 <EditItemTemplate>
  <asp:TextBox ID="nameEdit" runat="server" Text='<%#: Item.MasName %>'></asp:TextBox>
 </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<%--other columns--%>
```

Text binded to Label `nameLbl` show correctly: `Hříběcí hory`, but when I click auto generated edit button and text is binded to `TextBox` `nameEdit` (for editing entry), text is: `Hř&#237;běc&#237; hory`.

Where could be problem? Can I fix this for all records or do I have to set encoding to every TextBox (that I don't know how since I don't bind text in codebehind)

**EDIT:**

So I have rewrited `Text='<%#: Item.MasName %>'` to `Text='<%# Item.MasName %>'` and now it works. I was told that it's better to use `:` after `<%#` when I access data like this, but I can't find any article about what is this exactly doing.

Comment: Are you storing the text with the escape codes?

Comment: No, text is stored without escape codes, just `Hříběcí hory` f.e.

Comment: If you debug and inspect the Item.MasName property what do you get?  If you're happy the value is stored correctly you need to work out where in the chain the encoding occurs.

Comment: The value of `Item.MasName` is correct. There is something wrong with TextBox that for unknown reason converts `í` to `&#237;`.

Comment: This is likely a problem with content encodings on the web application side. This can get very tricky easily - the best way to make this work is to simply have UTF-8 everywhere, consistently. This means the content encoding of the HTTP response, the file encodings of all the source files... ASP.NET notices you're using a character that doesn't exist in the content encoding of the page, and replaces it with encoding-neutral version to make sure it displays correctly. Check the raw HTML of both the view and the edit mode, does it use the `&#237` string too?

Comment: I have `<meta charset="UTF-8"/>` on MasterPage. I have also tried `<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" fileEncoding="utf-8" responseHeaderEncoding = "utf-8"/>` and nothing helped. Yes I can see `&#237` in output html.